# How to use Doctrine Embeddables

Tags: doctrine-orm, embeddable

I'm trying to use Doctrine embeddables in a Symfony 2 project.

I have a class `Purchase` where I have a `price` field that is the embeddable:

```
/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="purchases")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Purchase
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\PriceEmbeddable")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param MoneyInterface $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice(MoneyInterface $price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return MoneyInterface|float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

}
```

As a price needs a currency to be complete, so I have the embeddable class that stores those two values:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class PriceEmbeddable
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type = "integer") */
    private $amount;

    /** @ORM\Column(type = "string") */
    private $currency;
}
```

**Now, the schema in the database is created correctly, but, when I persist the `Purchase` entity, I get the following error:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'price_amount' cannot be null

And I belive it: I'm yet not understanding how the mechanism works.

How I set and get values from the "real" entity (`Purchase`)?

**I pass the value as a `Money` object ([a value object I use](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPValueObjects/blob/master/src/Money/Money.php)) to the method `setPrice()` in the `Purchase`entity, but, how this value is splitted into the two properties `amount` and `currency` and set in the embeddable class?**

Because doing a `var_dump` (using the `dump()` function of [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html)) I get the Entity set the right way:

```
PurchaseListener.php on line 58:
Purchase {#1795 ▼
  ...
  -price: Money {#1000 ▼
    -amount: 86
    -currency: Currency {#925 ▼
      -currencyCode: "EUR"
    }
  }
}
```

**But those values are not set in the Embeddable** and I don't understand why...

I've also tried to hard code the values in the embedded class, but anyway it doesn't work and, again, I don't understand why:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class PriceEmbeddable
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type = "integer") */
    private $amount;

    /** @ORM\Column(type = "string") */
    private $currency;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->currency = 'EUR';
        $this->amount = 90;
    }

    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount = 90;
    }

    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency = 'EUR';
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple solution:

```
/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="purchases")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Purchase
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\PriceEmbeddable")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param PriceEmbeddable $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice(PriceEmbeddable $price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return PriceEmbeddable
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly instantiate `PriceEmbeddable` in your `Purchase` constructor:

```
class Purchase
{
  ...

  function __construct() {
      $this->price = new PriceEmbeddable();
  }

  ...

}
```